# Andel crankset, BB axle length and chainline

Tags: crankset, chainline

I was planning to buy an Andel Standard Track crankset. It uses 110mm axle bottom bracket, but the stock bracket on my bike is 103mm. Will this mess up my chainline?

[image]

Comment: This is on a single seed bike, right? What's the rear hub OLD spacing? Do you know what the nominal chainline of the bike is?

Comment: What you need to know is what chainline does this crank and the 110mm axle BB result in.

Answer (score 3):

It will be 3.5 mm off, and that is quite bad. Square taper bottom brackets aren't that expensive or difficult to replace, just get a correct one.

Comment: True. Furthermore, if you have BSC or Campy threading, you can easily put a cartridge bearings bottom bracket - much cleaner and easier to adjust during installation. And contrary to some beliefs, sealed bearings can still have their grease replaced.

Comment: Italian thread is a national standard, nothing campagnolo related. I don't think there is a reason to assume that original BB wasn't cartridge type.

Comment: Almost 2 years later and I have this exact same question. It turns out that the product listing says "use with 110mm JIS square-taper", but it does not include that bottom bracket. Does that mean I cannot install this on a 103mm square taper BB? Or is that just the shop making a recommendation?

Comment: Read the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Not only will it mess with your chainline (as already answered, 3.5mm off inwards), it may happen that you won't be able to mount this crankset at all in the first place.

<s>103mm</s>107mm bottom bracket is <s>standard</s>typical for road bikes with double or triple chainring in front although 103mm spindles are also available. In practice it means that the largest chainring is set out even more than a single one on a 110mm BB. And often it is just off the chainstay (the distance is only couple of millimetres). To be 100% sure you'd need to check what is the offset of your current crank and the one you want to buy.

Mounting a large chainring on a spindle that is too narrow may (and often does) cause the teeth to grind on the chainstay making pedalling impossible and irreversibly damaging your frame.

Chainline is the least problem here, thus.

Comment: Do you have actual measurements for the gap between chainring and chainstay on OP's bike? I'd also like a reference about 103mm being standard.

Comment: Curious about the 103mm standard too

Comment: I have chosen wrong wording and was a bit too fast with the numbers out of my head. The post is corrected accordingly.